# Make barrier blocks visible

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am creating an adventure map in 1.9 with an invisible maze. However, it is difficult to make it because I can't see the barrier blocks even when I hold a barrier block in creative. How do I make the barriers visible(only in creative)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### It's a particle

If you change the particles in settings to `All`, it will shown barrier blocks when holding a barrier.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, so you might want to do that to help future visitors.

Answer (score 8):

One thing you could do to make the barriers even more visible would be to create the maze with an unused block ie. dirt. Once finished, use `/fill <x> <y> <z> <dx> <dy> <dz> minecraft:barrier 0 replace minecraft:dirt` to turn it all into barrier blocks.

Comment: If you've already made a fair bit of the maze, you could use this command in reverse to turn all existing barriers to dirt.

Comment: By which he means swapping `minecraft:barrier` and `minecraft:dirt`

Answer (score 0):

If you turn particals to all the barrier icon will show up, on normal minecraft this is in esc ,options, video settings and if you use optifine it's
 esc options video settings animations.